# How to implement these Azure tags?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am creating a app gateway in Azure via terraform. I want to add these tags, but somehow it doesn't work.

```
  tags = ["AcceptedException_appgw-H-001", "AcceptedException_appgw-M-002", "AcceptedException_appgw-H-003"]
}
```

This is the message that I'm getting:

```
Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": map of string required.
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: We lack context. What should the tags represent? In other words, would it be a name? Environment? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Tags need to be defined like this with Key-value pairs:

```
tags = {
MyTagName = "Hello World Value"
AnotherTag = "Foo"
}
```

Sample [here](https://www.ntweekly.com/2021/11/25/add-tags-to-azure-resources-with-terraform/)